# Apache Lucene for Java: IndexWriter.addDocument vs addDocuments (speed)

Tags: java, apache, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I want to add a set of documents to my index: I currently use

```
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyElement myElement : myElementList) {
    documents.add(myElement.asLuceneDocument())
}
writer.addDocuments(documents)
```

Since addDocuments writes all of the documents with an atomic operation, i was wondering if adding a single document one by one was actually faster (I don't need atomicity in this case)

Comment: My first impression is that committing each document individually will make things slower than committing in batches. How many documents are you processing in the `for` loop? You'll probably will need to benchmark this to find a good batch size that works for you.

Comment: @HectorCorrea The number of documents per function call is very small 10-20, but i call this function thousands of times from as many concurrent threads as i can create